# After using image_rotate in R magick, I get wrong matrix

Tags: r, matrix, rotation, imagemagick

I want to get the matrix/array of a rotated image. I try to use image_rotate function in R package magick to realize this. However, when I try the following code

```
IM0 = image_read(path = "...") 
IM = image_rotate(IM0, 30)# where IM0 is the input image
M = as.numeric(IM[[1]])[,,1] # to get the matrix of the rotated image
image(M,asp=dim(M)[2]/dim(M)[1])
IM
```

The last two show different images. The later one is right, but the former, the image(...), looks like cut by the border, so is the matrix.
I wanna know how to get the right matrix after using image_rotate.

Answer (score 2):

If you save the image after rotating it, and read in the saved image, you will get the result you are looking for:

```r
library(magick)

IM0 <- image_read('trees.jpg')

IM0
```

[image]

```
IM = image_rotate(IM0, 30)
IM
```

[image]

```
image_write(IM, 'trees30.jpg')
IM30 <- image_read('trees30.jpg')
IM30
```

[image]

```
M <- as.numeric(IM30[[1]])
image(M[,,1])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this before I ask, but I still get the same result before I save the image. But I use another R package "png", and the function readPNG(...) helps me. Does the gray image effect the result? Because I try on color image and it succeeds too, even without saving and reloading.

Comment: Finally I try to use image_composite to combine a white background and the rotated image together and it works. I am not sure the cause and get confused T^T